# how to get the SOAP request of a Sharepoint web service from its method name

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, soap

I would like to get the SOAP request XML of a Sharepoint web service by providing the method name.

For example, if I want the SOAP request message for the `GetListCollection` method, what do I need to do?

Comment: Hi Thabet, please do a little research - or show us [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so we have a starting point.

Comment: What do you mean, "the SOAP request message"?

Comment: I mean the xml representing the soap request

Comment: If you are only looking for the soap message you can load the wsdl into soapUI...

Comment: Which request? Are you expecting to get a block of XML with placeholders for the paramters? Won't happen. It doesn't work that way. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to send soap request using a customized http requests. Let me rephrase my questions: would it be possible to modify the soap messages using SOAPExtension or other in order to set the values of the placeholders ? Otherwise, how would I enter values of placeholders in the soap message ?

Comment: Another point is that I am trying to do this generically, i.e. for any web-service I would modify the soap message in order to enter the required values, send it and catch the response